# How to create an intersection with complexity in O (n)?

Tags: c++

I need to create a function that intersects two vectors: `vectorA ∩ vectorB` and allocates the values ​​found in this intersection in a `vectorC`!

**Rules:**

- (a) The **complexity** of the **function/method** must be:

  **O(n)**, `if n> m`

  **O(m)**, `if m> n`
- (b) The **complexity** of the **program (function / main method)** must be:

  **O(n log n)**, `if n > m`

  **O(m log m)**, `if m > n`
- c) The signing of the function of intersection shall be **obligatorily**:

`void intersections (char a [], int n, char b [], int m, char c [], int * k)`

- d) Predefined language functions can **not be used** to treat vectors (search, pertinence, insertion, deletion, ordering, etc.).

I was thinking of using an **algorithm of complexity O(n)** which is called **"Linear Time"**. However this algorithm makes it "linear" comparison obviously as the name says.

**Example:**

```
A = { 'E', 'C', 'B', 'J', 'S', 'F', 'C', 'V', 'G' }
B = { 'G', 'C', 'M', 'W', 'L', 'O' }
C = { 'G', 'C' }
```

**How far have I come?**

> Currently I can fetch and compare the corresponding values ​​for the intersection.

**What is my difficulty?**

> 1) The values ​​after the comparison can not be added to the vector `char c[]` with repetitions. How to prevent the same?
>
> 2) How to use the pointer `int *k` (which is the size of the vector `char c[]`) and allocate the corresponding values ​​without repetitions to it?

```
bool checkHasStringEqual(char vectorA, char vectorB) {
    string stringA, stringB;
    stringA = toupper(vectorA),
    stringB = toupper(vectorB);

    size_t found = stringA.find(stringB);

    return (found != std::string::npos);
}

void intersection(char a[], char b[], char c[], int n, int m, int *k){
    int indexA = 0, indexB = 0, counterIntersection = 0;

    if(n > m) {
        while(indexA < n) {
            if(indexB != m) {
                if(checkHasStringEqual(a[indexA], b[indexB])) {
                    cout << "STRING A: " << a[indexA] << " == " << "STRING B: " << b[indexB] << endl;
                    counterIntersection++;
                }

                cout << "( " << a[indexA] << "-->" << b[indexB] << ")" << " -- " << "( " << indexA << ", " << indexB << ")" << endl;
                (indexA == n -1) ? (indexA = 0, indexB++) : indexA++;

            } else {
                cout << "CAME TO THE END OF THE ANALYSIS" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(m > n) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags to your question. It probably annoys people looking for questions with specific tags.

Comment: @FeiXiang I apologize, I added the C tag, because as the algorithm has library usage restrictions, probably people connected to the C language would like to know about this question.

Comment: you only can do O(m) or O(n) if both list are sorted, are there?

Comment: @nimamoradi No, they are out of order, I was able to do the search and the comparison, now it is in `O(n)` and / or `O(m)`. For if I do the ordering in case it would be `O(n log n`), only the ordering and joining with the intersection would be + `O(n)` and would not be the Order that is requested. How do I develop the correct code for an order `(n)` or `(m)` for the given function, knowing that int main must have `O(n log n)` and / or `O(m log m)`?

Comment: `toupper` returns an integer type value so it won't be compatible with string type variables `stringA`, `stringB`. Since you are comparing charater type variables, you can simply set it to `return toupper(vectorA) == toupper(vectorB);` instead of going through all the trouble of using `find()`.

Comment: @VietHTran Annotated tip, could you answer the rest? If you formalize a response, healing all my doubts I will give the same as the correct one and punctuate you.

Comment: What makes you think your function has the required complexity? If I were you I would scrap this and get back to the drawing board ASAP, for fear of not getting any points for this assignment.

Comment: The O(n log n) required complexity of main strongly suggests that main is responsible for somehow sorting the input sequences. Then you need to exploit the property of being sorted in order to achieve the required complexity of your intersect function.

Comment: @n.m. The temporal complexity of an algorithm quantifies the portion of time that an algorithm takes to rotate as a function of the size of the input of the problem. Taking this knowledge and analyzing my algorithm, is O (n) ... Could you provide me with an answer, helping me with the required question and based on your comments? I really understand what are complexities, I know the algorithms to use such as: (Logarithmic Time: Binary Search and Linear Time: Merge sort, among others), but I can not create them according to the statement .. I I would be grateful for your wisdom.

Comment: Sorry your code is really, really misleading. You are calling `find` on two std::strings of length 1. I didn't notice this at first. This makes no sense whatsoever. Instead of doing that you could just `return toupper(vectorA) == toupper(vectorB)` . The choice of variable names is really confusing too. However this algorithm is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The stated task is doable in linear time using a single lookup table, even without sorting, due to the significantly restricted domain size being managed. `char` has at-most `1 << CHAR_BIT` distinct representations. On *almost* all systems that is simply 8-bits, or 256 possible values. A char16_t  would use 16 bits, or 65536 possible representations, and of course, a char32_t, would have over 2-billion representations.

I'm assuming we're in the domain of the first one, or even two, of these, and not the last. Given that, this is doable with a single markup table indexed by all possible values within the domain. The algorithm is simple:

1. Start with an table of markers, size = `1 << CHAR_BIT`, all initialized to `false`.
2. Enumerate either input sequence.

   - For each character take the `unsigned char` equivalent as an index into the markup table, setting the table value to `true`
3. Enumerate the *other* input sequence.

   - For each character take the `unsigned char` equivalent value as an index into he markup table. If the value is `true`, clear it to `false` and add that character to the output sequence.

When finished, the result will be a unique-set-intersection of the two input character sequences. An example is given below. As it (and many other things) was not specified, I took liberty to make `k` an in/out argument. On input it refers to the maximum number of chars that can fit in `C[]`, On output it contains the number of chars actually stored.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

void mk_intersection(char a[], int n, char b[], int m, char c[], int * k)
{
    bool tbl[1 << CHAR_BIT] = { 0 };

    int o = *k;
    *k = 0;

    // markup a[]
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        tbl[static_cast<unsigned char>(a[i])] = true;

    // filter b[] from markup
    for (int i = 0; i < m && *k < o; ++i)
    {
        if (tbl[static_cast<unsigned char>(b[i])])
        {
            tbl[static_cast<unsigned char>(b[i])] = false;
            c[(*k)++] = b[i];
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char A[] = { 'E', 'C', 'B', 'J', 'S', 'F', 'C', 'V', 'G' };
    char B[] = { 'G', 'C', 'M', 'W', 'L', 'O' };
    char C[std::max(sizeof A, sizeof B)] = { 0 };
    int c_len = sizeof C;

    mk_intersection(A, sizeof A, B, sizeof B, C, &c_len);

    for (int i = 0; i < c_len; ++i)
        std::cout.put(C[i]);
    std::cout.put('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
GC
```

That's it. Regarding your question of "how to make `main` O(n log n), frankly, that's nonsense. It implies that you can, at your discretion, presort the input before invoking your intersection operation. In doing so you can implement your function using a simple one-pass merge, which would work, and not have the domain-size limit I've described earlier. But for this example it is neither needed, nor warranted. It isn't required. And frankly, both arguments `a[]` and `b[]` could (and should) be `const`.

Comment: I ran your code and found something strange in a test, which was as follows ...

1) If I enter the vectorA of size 5, vectorB of size 3 and add the characters "abcde" and cde respectively, the result in vectorC will be "cd", it did not get the "e", it looks like it does not go until final.

2) If I type the uppercase character for vectorA and lowercase for vectorB, even though they are respective it does not find the intersection.

Could you supplement in your answer so I give as the correct one?

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS Regarding your first assertion (does not go until final) I find that very hard to believe. You changed something. The above code, given exactly as presented, and changing only the inputs to be the strings you specify, works correctly. [See it live](https://ideone.com/yoLyri). Regarding your second point, case-insensitivity was never part of the posted question in any form. It is not mentioned in the "Rules" not any part of the posted question. Had it been I *may* have included it. It won't be hard, so I leave it as a challenge for you. It is, after all, your homework.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't worry about using too much memory, you can initialize 2 256-element integer arrays `a_set`, `b_set` which will be used to keep track of the occurrence of each character from 0-255 in array `a` and `b`, respectively. By using `a_set`, you will add any character `chr` from `b` to `c` if and only if `a_set[chr]` is equal to 1 and `b_set[chr]` is equal to 0. After adding `chr` to `c`, you will set `b_set[chr]=1;` in order to avoid repetitions of characters.

The time complexity for this approach is `O(n + m) --> O(max(n,m))`.

I also added the `main` method below so you can check if it is your desired output for `C` and `k`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool checkHasStringEqual(char vectorA, char vectorB) {
    return toupper(vectorA) == toupper(vectorB);
}

void intersection(char a[], char b[], char c[], int n, int m, int *k){
    int indexA = 0, indexB = 0, counterIntersection = 0;
    unsigned char chr;
    // unsigned char can only go from 0-255
    int a_set[256] = {0}; // initialize array to 0
    int b_set[256] = {0}; // initialize array to 0
    *k = 0; // initialize k value to 0

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        chr = a[i];
        a_set[chr] = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        chr = b[i];
        if (a_set[chr] && !b_set[chr]) {
            c[*k] = b[i]; 
            (*k)++; // increase k index
        }
        b_set[chr] = 1; // mark character as inserted
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = 9;
    int m = 6;
    int k;
    char A[n] = { 'E', 'C', 'B', 'J', 'S', 'F', 'C', 'V', 'G' };
    char B[m] = { 'G', 'C', 'M', 'W', 'L', 'O' };
    char C[max(n, m)]; // C will contain at most maximum of n, m elements

    intersection(A, B, C, n, m, &k);
    cout << "Intersection: " << endl; 
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        cout << C[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```